# My update function doesn't set values to null after saving

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I received help to solve how to delete files uploaded by using the Cakephp Upload package. However, there seems to be a problem with how I update the values of the `photo` and `dir` fields. By using unlink I was able to delete the files perfectly, but there seems to be a problem when I try to set the values to null. I made a function to test it out:

```
public function deletePhoto2($id)
{
    // $this->request->allowMethod(['post']);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

        $brigada = $this->Brigadas
                    ->findById($id)
                    ->firstOrFail();

        $brigada->dir = null;
        $brigada->photo = null;

        if ($this->Brigadas->save($brigada)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your team data has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $brigada->id]);
        }

        $this->set('brigada', $brigada);
    }
}
```

Before saving I find that the value of `$brigada->photo` and `$brigada->dir` are null, but values don't save. I have several possibilities that want to explore but my knowledge of PHP is a hindrance:

1. I may be doing updates wrong. [Link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data)
2. I may need to use the deleteCallback which is documented [here](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2015/12/05/uploading-files-and-images/), but I don't know how to do it. I figured that it would be with `$this->Brigadas->deleteCallback()` or something similar, but I'd like to understand an example first, which is why I'm asking. I found no use of these callbacks in any example on the web, [and the documentation on events is still a bit esoteric for me.](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html)

Here is how BrigadasTable.php is setup to upload files:

```
    // http://josediazgonzalez.com/2015/12/05/uploading-files-and-images/
    $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
        'photo' => [
            'fields' => [
                'dir' => 'dir',
                'size' => 'photo_size', // defaults to `size`
                'type' => 'photo_type', // defaults to `type`
            ],

            'nameCallback' => function ($table, $entity, $data, $field, $settings) {
                if ($entity->gvCode){
                    $array = explode(".", $data['name']);
                    return strtolower($entity->gvCode) . '_' . date("Ymd-hisa") . '.jpg';

                } else{
                    $array = explode(".", $data['name']);
                    $newArray = array_pop($array);
                    return strtolower(join('_', $array)) . '_' . date("Ymd-hisa") . '.jpg';
                }
            },

            'transformer' =>  function ($table, $entity, $data, $field, $settings) {

                $extension = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                // Store the thumbnail in a temporary file
                $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload') . '.' . $extension;

                // Use the Imagine library to DO THE THING
                $size = new \Imagine\Image\Box(640, 640);
                $mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
                $imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

                // Save that modified file to our temp file
                $imagine->open($data['tmp_name'])
                    ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
                    ->save($tmp);

                $filenameTmp = explode('.', $data['name']);
                array_pop($filenameTmp);
                $filenameTmp = join('_', $filenameTmp) . '.jpg';
                // return debug($filenameTmp);

                // Now return the original *and* the thumbnail
                return [
                    $data['tmp_name'] => $filenameTmp,
                    $tmp => 'thumbnail-' . $filenameTmp,
                ];
            },

            'deleteCallback' => function ($path, $entity, $field, $settings) {
                // When deleting the entity, both the original and the thumbnail will be removed
                // when keepFilesOnDelete is set to false

                $entity->{$field} = null;

                return [
                    $path . $entity->{$field},
                    $path . 'thumbnail-' . $entity->{$field}

                ];
            },
            'keepFilesOnDelete' => false
        ]
    ]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it say that it saved, but actually doesn't? Or does the save fail?

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding earlier, @GregSchmidt. It did say that it saved (I would debug whether the function returned successfully). It just didn't update anything at all. I think that I was going everything correctly, as it did edit the call before saving, but right after saving it didn't return anything. I'm curious of the reason for this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it did edit the call before saving, but right after saving it didn't return anything", so I can't really comment on what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Sorry, let me try again. When I debug before ```if ($this->Brigadas->save($brigada))```, I get ```dir``` and ```photo``` as null, but not after the save function.

Comment: Oh, maybe the Upload behavior is setting them even in this case? Try removing the behavior from the model before saving in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an update query straight, instead of fetching the record, setting values and saving it.

```
$query = $this->Brigadas->query();
$query->update()
    ->set([
            'dir' => null,
            'photo' => null,
         ])
    ->where(<condition>)
    ->execute();
```

Incase any of your columns are json,

```
$query = $this->Brigadas->query();
$query->update()
    ->set([
            'dir = null',
            'photo' => null,
         ])
    ->where(<condition>)
    ->execute();
```

Comment: This works! I'm so happy, thanks so much! Should I put my ```unlink``` in a different function in the controller or is there a way to do it without fetching the record? What do you recommend?

Comment: @E.Velis Running `unlink` first and then updating the database seems to make more sense.